# Removing entire line with sed not working?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a line which looks like this: `</File2>`. I want to remove it using `sed`, but nothing I tried worked, I tried

```
sed '/^<\/File2>$/d'
```

so I thought maybe theres special characters at the end, but:

```
sed '/^<\/File2>/d'
```

didn't work either. I cannot remove the `^` in the beginning, because's there's lines I want to keep that includes `</File2>`.

Comment: your first command is working for me. Is it possible there are more than one  whitespaces at the end? May be try `sed '/^<\/File2>.*$/d'`

Comment: @Ketan nothing happens when I run that command, as with the ones I provided. It should work the same way as `sed '/^<\/File2>/d'` either way.

Comment: Works for me. What version of `sed` do you use?

Comment: @pfnuesel I can't find which version I am using, `--version` doesn't exist in my version atleast, but it's a BSD version and the manpage was written in 2005.

Comment: This is your second post today regarding parsing `xml` with regex. See the following: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1032785

Comment: @jordanm I have read that multiple times. It's a childish answer and says nothing. This is also not complicated at all and `sed` should be able to handle it, the reason `sed` is failing is not because of the tags.

Comment: Have you looked for special characters not at the end?

Comment: In fact, could you just **provide your actual data**? "I have some data that behaves this way" isn't terribly helpful, especially when you suspect hidden characters. hexdump it if necessary.

Comment: @MichaelHomer It's the acutal data. It's an XML that is going to be converted into SQL later on and the column is called File2, but it has lines just containing `</File2>` (I can't remove them by hand since it's so many files). I never said I have some data "that behaves this day", I said "I have a line that looks like this". Of course it's not a file with only that but the line I am trying to remove looks like that. And there might be special characters Stackexchange can't handle, but I copied that directly from one of the files.

Comment: No, it isn't, it's a statement that says "I have a line which looks like this: `</File2>`.". You've described what it looks like. **Provide an example input *that reproduces your problem***. Use `hexdump` (or `hd`) to represent it if necessary.

Comment: Alternatively, you could post a minimal reproducing file off-site. Just some way that people can see *exactly* what's in there, because that's going to be what diagnoses the problem.

Comment: use `xmlstarlet` or some other XML processing tool.  `perl` and `python` and many other languages have several good XML parser libraries available.  Use the right tool for the job.  regexp is not a magic universal hammer, and not every problem is a nail.

Comment: just in case `sed 's:</File2>::'` won't do the job ?

Comment: @cas This is simple enough to not need a parser for. Regex did the job fine, it was just that it was some weird format fixable with `tr -d '\r'` which revealed a whole new xml tag and a space before `<\/File2>`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Running `tr -d '\r'` on the file before removing the lines work.

No idea why, but when I ran this command it revealed another tag as well as a space before `<\/File2>`.

Comment: Not sure why I was down voted. It worked.